# Definition diagonal arbitrary quadrilateral

Tags: analytic-geometry

### Given

A convex quadrilateral whose sides are defined as (a=200, b=140, c=180, d=160). Diagonally (d1, d2) are equal.

### Task

How to determine the length of the diagonal (d1, d2) with up to six decimal places?

### Numerical results

Obtained in Mathcad using the Find function: 241.6579007199

Thanks

Comment: So are you satisfied with a numerical solution (because this is what you are asking for - six decimal places)? Or are you interested in how exactly your program computed this and how you can do it analytically?

Comment: I'm interested in an algorithm for solving the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\angle(a,b)$ (the angle between the sides $a$ and $b$) and $\beta=\angle(a,d)$. For any given angle $\alpha$ you can compute exactly one angle $\beta$ (using basic geometry), so that the side $c$ has the desirded length *and* the quadrilateral is convex. So, essentially, you have a single parameter to determin: $\alpha$. Now use your favorite optimizations scheme to find $\alpha$ in such a way, that the diagonals are of equal length, e.g.:

- [Bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)
- [Newtons method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

These procedures are searching for a zero of a function in a single variable. So for example try to find the zero of $f(\alpha):=|d_1(\alpha)-d_2(\alpha)|$, which is the difference in the length of the diagonals. If this functions is zero, the diagonals are of the same length.

Comment: In this quadrangle all angles of vertices differ (see. [figure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Gy5OzgV1IbbFpHZ1dCMkk4OUU)).

Comment: I applied a decision by the ratio of the square (see. [example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Gy5OzgV1IbWUR3ZmxVSjA0S3c))

Comment: This task has a purely algebraic solution (see. [cubic equation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Gy5OzgV1IbT3c5Yi1UTVpGMnM))